# SQL : Optimize Union Query to get updated/inserted rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, union

I want to capture all rows whose values have changed based on a datetime column that gets modified on any update/insert.

There is one parent table, and couple of child tables.

I am using UNION to do this but it it slow. What are my alternatives? How can I better structure the query to run in much lesser time?

```
Tables -  
ParentT - Rowid(PK),column1,last_update 
ChildT1 - column1,last_update,parent_rowid(FK to ParentT.Rowid) 
ChiltT2 - column1,last_update,parent_rowid(FK to ParentT.Rowid) 
ChildT3 - column1,last_update,parent_rowid(FK to ParentT.Rowid)
```

Query :

```
SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT
WHERE Rowid IN (
   SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT pT WHERE pT.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT1 cT1 WHERE cT1.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT2 cT2 WHERE cT2.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT3 cT3 WHERE cT3.last_update > somedatetime
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using IN, you do not require distinct values... So please use UNION ALL instead of UNION. UNION does union and tries to do de-duplication which is complex process and does not require for your query

You can change your query as below:

```
SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT
WHERE Rowid IN (
   SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT pT WHERE pT.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION ALL --Added ALL
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT1 cT1 WHERE cT1.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION ALL --Added ALL
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT2 cT2 WHERE cT2.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION ALL --Added ALL
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT3 cT3 WHERE cT3.last_update > somedatetime
)
```

Comment: For my data, UNION is performing better than UNION ALL.

Comment: What is index on ParentT table and Child tables?

Comment: If you are able to provide execution plan that will be good to further analyze

Answer (score 0):

Use separate conditions:

```
SELECT Rowid
FROM ParentT
WHERE Rowid IN (SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT pT WHERE pT.last_update > somedatetime) OR
      Rowid IN (SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT1 cT1 WHERE cT1.last_update > somedatetime) OR
      Rowid IN (SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT2 cT2 WHERE cT2.last_update > somedatetime) OR
      Rowid IN (SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT3 cT3 WHERE cT3.last_update > somedatetime);
```

This allows each query to be optimized independently, making use of available indexes, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Rowid FROM ParentT PT
WHERE pT.last_update > somedatetime and exists  (

   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT1 cT1 WHERE cT1.Rowid=pt.Rowid 
   and  cT1.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION ALL --Added ALL
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT2 cT2 WHERE cT2.Rowid=pt.Rowid 
   and cT2.last_update > somedatetime
   UNION ALL --Added ALL
   SELECT Parent_rowid FROM ChildT3 cT3 WHERE cT3.Rowid=pt.Rowid 
   and cT3.last_update > somedatetime
)
```